# Bash - for files in "$@"; do

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a script containing few blocks with the following code:

```
for files in "$@"; do
echo "${files}"
#command
done
```

Some of the commands in the beginning of the script create new files in the folder. I have noticed that `for files in "$@"; do` ignores the new files in the folder though.
So if I ran `myscript.sh file1 file2 file3` where `myscript.sh` starts with:

```
for files in "$@"; do
echo "${files}"
#command reads file1 file2 file3 and creates file4 file5 file6
done
```

and then there is one more block of code:

```
for files in "$@"; do
echo "${files}"
#another command
done
```

The 2nd appearance of `for files in "$@"; do` will still read the original `file1 file2 file3` and ignore the newly created `file4 file5 file6`

I am wondering if that is always a case. Sorry I was not able to find any related info in man pages and therefore asking someone to confirm that.

Comment: `$@` expands to the list of parameters specified in the command line. You probably wanted to use `for files in *; do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"$@"` gives you the list of command-line arguments passed to your script. It has no particular connection to a list of file names, or the files in the current directory. It's just the arguments from the command line.

If you want to loop over the files in the current directory, you could write:

```
for file in *
```

Or for ones in a different directory:

```
for file in /some/other/dir/*
```

Comment: so basically if I ran my scipt using myscript.sh file1 file2 file3, $@ is $1 (file1), $2 (file2) and $3 (file3)m correct?

Comment: How about if I ran the script using myscript.sh /path/to/folder/containing/files ? Will the number of $1 $2 $3 etc. change in the process of running the script?

Comment: `myscript.sh /path/to/folder/containing/files` will only set `$1` to "/path/to/folder/containing/files". `myscript.sh /path/to/folder/containing/files/*` will pass a list of files in that directory. But the list will not update -- the argument list is a list of strings, not some sort of dynamically-updating pattern.

Answer (score -1):

`"$@"` is all your command arts as a single token, albeit with embedded blanks. Your `for file ...` loop is iterating exactly once. See what `set -vx` tells you.

Comment: This isn't correct, it treats each argument as a separate token. From the [bash reference manual, special parameters section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters): '@ ... Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …'

Comment: Thanks for catching my bad.